# How can I Replicate data from RETS server to my local server?

Tags: php, rets

Right now I am working on one Real Estate Website, In that website I am using RETS Service to get property data.I want to replicate that data to my local server so, I am stuck with database design for replicate that RETS data.I want sample DB for RETS data handle or help me how to make database for RETS data replication?

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use libRETS for your interface, then transcribe the RETS class schema into a comparable local sql table.  Hopefully the MLS will have a created & modified data table so you can iterate over each class at set intervals and insert/update records as needed.

Note:
Rets to SQL;  A RETS class is a SQL table, a RETS table is a SQL column.

Answer (score 0):

For every RETS class, you can create separate tables and the columns corresponding to each system name with the data type specified in the RETS.